# How does Sam know Quorra is an ISO?

Tags: tron-legacy

When they jump the freight train, Kevin Flynn starts to repair Quorra. This seems to be just a normal thing in repairing a program, but in the middle of doing so, Sam says is looking at the code which looks like some sort of digital DNA,

> She's an ISO

How does he know that she is an ISO just by looking at something he obviously has never seen before?

Answer (score 4):

The previous line was a bit of a giveaway.

> **Flynn:** *I've got to identify the damaged code. The sequencing is just enormously complex.*
>
> **Sam:** *But didn't you write it?*
>
> **Flynn:** *Some of it. **The rest of it is just beyond me.***

especially given that he's already talked about the ISOs emerging from chaos

> **Sam:** *And you created them?*
>
> **Flynn:** *No. No. They manifested, like a flame.*